# Azure Sphere: Unique Device ID at Application Layer

Tags: azure-sphere

I am working on an Azure Sphere project and would like to programmatically get the unique device ID, preferably the ID generated by the device when the device is claimed - is this possible, and if so how?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

getting the device ID programmatically on the device ID is not supported on Azure Sphere today. The challenge with supporting this is that using device ID for authentication is not encouraged compared to the Device Authentication and Attestation (DAA) certificate.

Can you provide some details on why you need the device ID?